# VBScript SQL Bulk Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, vbscript

I have a simple sql bulk insert statement that works well inside sql mgmt studios. I'm trying to run the sql command from a .vbs file. Here is my vbscript code. It makes it all the way to the msgbox and displays the message. It doesn't show any errors so it appears to be completing, but the table is blank in the db so no data was imported. What am I missing?

```
option explicit

Dim objConn
Dim objRS
Dim strSQL
Dim ConnectionString

Dim fso             
Dim objArgs

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=mtgops047-db006;Database=interlinqe3;Trusted_Connection=yes"

Set objConn = CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject ("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objConn.Open ConnectionString

strSQL = "delete from Settlement_Import_Data"
strSQL = strSQL & " BULK INSERT Settle_Import_Data"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM '\\server\sharedfolder\importdata.txt' with"
strSQL = strSQL & " ( FIELDTERMINATOR =',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')"


Set objRS = Nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn = Nothing
MsgBox ("Update Complete!") 
WScript.Quit()
```

Comment: There is nothing that "runs" the sql string you built.  You're missing something like `objConn.Execute(strSQL)`

Comment: Try adding a semicolon or a line break between the two statements.  Not certain if ADO supports either but it's an easy test.

Comment: The line break looks to be the issue. It's only running the first command. How do I add the line break?

Comment: Just call `objConn.Execute()` once for your `delete` statement and call it again for your `bulk insert` statement. You also don't need a Recordset or FileSystemObject here.

Answer (score 0):

objConn.Execute() once for your delete statement and call it again for your bulk insert statement solved the issue. Thanks!